# T-SQL combine tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want a+b to get to C. How do I combine A and B ?

Thanks :)

Table A

```
SELECT init, MIN(p.aarstal) AS startyear
FROM placering p
GROUP BY init
ORDER BY startyear
```

Table B

```
SELECT init, MAX(p.aarstal) AS endyear
FROM placering p
GROUP BY init 
ORDER BY endyear
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're the same table, so you just need to combine the logic of both queries. See below for an example.

```
SELECT 
  p.init, 
  min(p.aarstal) as startyear, 
  max(p.aarstal) as endyear
FROM placering p
GROUP BY init
ORDER BY startyear, endyear
```

Answer (score 1):

You just select both expressions in a single `select`:

```
select init, min(p.aarstal) as startyear, max(p.aarstal) as endyear
from placering p
group BY init
order by startyear
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for this ?

```
SELECT init, min(p.aarstal) as startyear, max(p.aarstal) as endyear
FROM placering p
GROUP BY init
ORDER BY startyear, endyear
```